# Rails multi-select enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, rails-activerecord, cross-database

I want to implement an enumerable multi-select field on any arbitrary model without defining options in the database. This would be useful in any situation where an object could be categorized in multiple ways, but you want to limit which categories are available. User roles would be well-implemented in this way because it would allow users to have multiple roles without depending on the database to define those roles (in other words, you would avoid the anti-pattern of having hard-coded values depend on dynamic database data).

I've looked online for a solution to this problem, but have not found any mention of enumerable multi-select gems or code implementations, and I'm still a bit fresh on rails. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This post should go _Odesk_ or equivalent.. :) It is a requirement..

Comment: I figure this isn't a rare need, and in many other areas, rails is well designed and implemented. Keeping a solution to this problem proprietary would be a sad loss in my opinion.

Comment: @Adam just searching for something similar - https://github.com/bbtfr/simple_enum-multiple how about this, have you tried. Or how did you tackle it ?